# Getting null body in response from feign client, even though a direct request is returning an entity

Tags: spring-boot, openfeign

I have this Feign Client in my spring boot application :

```
@Component
@FeignClient(value = "apiKeyManager", url = "http://localhost:8081/", configuration = FileUploadConfiguration.class)
public interface ApiKeyClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/public/getAppName", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity getAppName(@RequestBody AppNameRequestDto appNameRequestDto);
}
```

And I have this code in my service, which calls it :

```
        AppNameRequestDto request = new AppNameRequestDto(apiKey);

        ResponseEntity verification = apiKeyClient.getAppName(request);

        return verification;
```

The actual endpoint being called by the feign client looks like this :

```
    @PostMapping(value = "getAppName", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity getAppName(@RequestBody AppNameRequestDto appNameRequestDto){
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity(apiKeyManagementService.getAppName(appNameRequestDto.getApiKey()), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity("Failed to locate application by API_KEY : " + appNameRequestDto.getApiKey(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
```

When I run this code - I get this response :

```
{
    "headers": {
        <REMOVED FOR BREVITY>
    },
    "body": null,
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "statusCodeValue": 200
}
```

But when I make the call to the underlying API directly, I get the response I am expecting - an entity with an accompanies 200 status :

```
{
    "applicationName": "MyNewFileUploadServiceApplication6"
}
```

Comment: ResponseEntity accepts a generic argument <T>. You are defining a ResponseEntity without generic data type. So Try to create a class to define your reseponse (the one with the "applicationName" attribute), let`s call it MyResponse, and on your feign client define the return type with: ResponseEntity<MyResponse>. This way feign will know how to desserialize your response body.

Comment: BRILLIANT, THANKS!